# How to fix custom Terminal prompt with export PS1="\W \$"; clear; that becomes \W $

Tags: bash, terminal, macos-big-sur

I am installing dev tools on a new MacBook Air (M1) with Big Sur and the default terminal prompt is too long and includes my user name and host, so I found [instructions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34910/how-to-hide-computer-name-and-user-name-in-terminal-command-prompt) on how to customize it.

Using the Terminal's preference window, I added this code.

```sh
export PS1="\W \$"; clear;
```

but when I launch the terminal, I get this prompt

```sh
\W $
```

I replaced W with other options, but they are never processed - I just get the literal string.

I suspect it has to do with the config file format for Terminal.

Comment: Note that the default shell on Mac has changed from bash to `zsh`. It may be that you are using bash-specific prompt codes instead of zsh ones.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_. Questions about configuring your interactive shell are a better fit for [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (or, should they be Mac-specific, [apple.se]).

Comment: lower case:  PS1="\u@\h--> \w\n$ " for bash

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the `\W` is specific to bash.

Nowadays, the default macOS shell is zsh. See [this page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html) for some zsh prompt options

I am unable to test it on my Windows machine, but

```
PS1="%1~ $"
```

looks similar to `\W` to me.

Of course, if you want to configure your terminal to use bash, that's also an option.

Answer (score 1):

I have something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export BEEP=$(echo -en "\007")
LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
export PS1=$LIGHT_GRAY"\u@\h $GREEN\w : $BEEP"
```

Works for me to give:

```sh
robevans@Robs-Machine ~ : [start_typing_here_in_green]
```

with an audible sound (not a beep but macOS's 'chime') when a command's execution is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Create `.zshrc` file at user root and paste text. Follow steps mentioned below.

1. Run this command `vi ~/.zshrc`
2. Press `i` button in keyboard to enter in edit mode
3. Copy and paste this text into vi editor `export PS1="%~ $ "`
4. Press `Esc` button in keyboard
5. Press `Shift + :` button in keyboard
6. Press `wq` button in keyboard and press `Enter`
7. Restart your terminal by simply close and open again.

It Works!

For more configuration check documentation https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your `.bashrc` file:

```
export PS1='\W $'
```

Comment: `export` is bad form here altogether -- it means that the same PS1 is shared by all subprocesses, even if they aren't bash. Moreover, we don't know that the OP's shell _is_ bash in the first place; zsh is now default on Mac OS. And beyond that, Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing software, and off-topic questions shouldn't be answered -- see the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and particularly the bullet point linking to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.